# error in pyspark download on google collab

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, google-colaboratory

i am very new to python and pyspark, i have a project to do and we are using pyspark on google collab and i was using the code below, its been going fine until today i cant seem to install spark anymore. If anybody can help me i will very much appreciate it!

i was using this code :

```
!wget -q https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.0/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
!tar -xzf spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz
!pip install -q findspark


import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3"

import findspark
findspark.init()
```

and i am getting now this error :

```
tar (child): spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3.tgz: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    158         try:
--> 159             py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    160         except IndexError:

IndexError: list index out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Exception                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
1 frames
<ipython-input-20-a05079ca17b7> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 
     11 import findspark
---> 12 findspark.init()

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/findspark.py in init(spark_home, python_path, edit_rc, edit_profile)
    159             py4j = glob(os.path.join(spark_python, "lib", "py4j-*.zip"))[0]
    160         except IndexError:
--> 161             raise Exception(
    162                 "Unable to find py4j in {}, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly".format(
    163                     spark_python

Exception: Unable to find py4j in /content/spark-3.5.0-bin-hadoop3/python, your SPARK_HOME may not be configured correctly
```

Comment: [the link](https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.0/) you're using is not valid. check available version [here](https://dlcdn.apache.org/spark/).

Answer (score 0):

after doing more research i found that there is a new version and the website i was using became suddenly not valid so here's the new code that worked for me:

```
!apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq > /dev/null

!wget -q https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz

!tar xf spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz

!pip install -q findspark

import os

os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"

os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "/content/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3"

import findspark

findspark.init()
```